# Loop every month to filter the date by each month in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, datepicker

This loop iterates over each selected date of the month but isn't highlighting all the selected dates of each month but first.
Please have a look and suggest a better approach or correct it to work properly.

```
for (var eachDate = 0; eachDate < selectedArrayLength; eachDate++) 
{
    if (ind == new Date(selected[eachDate]).getMonth()) 
    {
        var selectedDates = {};
        selectedDates[new Date(selected[eachDate])] = new Date(selected[eachDate]);
        var highlightMe = new Array();
        highlightMe.push(new Date(selected[eachDate]));
        console.log(highlightMe);

        line.datepicker({ disabled: false, defaultDate: d, beforeShowDay: function (dateToHighlight)
        {
             var Highlight = selectedDates[dateToHighlight];
             if (Highlight)
             {
                 return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
             }
             else 
             {
                 return [true, '', ''];
             }
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the log of a test run of this loop.

```
"calendar0" Multi.html:135
Array [ Date 2015-01-01T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-01-08T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-01-15T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-01-22T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-01-29T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-01-29T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:160

"calendar1" Multi.html:135
Array [ Date 2015-02-05T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-02-12T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-02-19T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-02-26T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-02-26T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:160

"calendar2" Multi.html:135
Array [ Date 2015-03-05T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-03-12T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-03-19T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-03-26T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-03-26T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:160

"calendar3" Multi.html:135
Array [ Date 2015-04-02T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-04-09T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-04-16T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-04-23T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-04-23T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:160

"calendar4" Multi.html:135
Array [ Date 2015-04-30T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-05-07T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-05-14T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:144
Array [ Date 2015-05-14T19:00:00.000Z ] Multi.html:160
```

Comment: Could you include the output of your `console.log(highlightMe);`?

Comment: using date objects as property keys for another object doesn't make much sense. Suggest you create a  demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Also... might be helpful to add a `console.log(dateToHighlight);` inside the `beforeShowDay` callback and include a few of those too.

Comment: @ZougenMoriver log is added in the question. It is just highlighting the very first date from each section.